# API NET CORE: Error:400 "'I' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this error when call a service from a page with ajax:

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|5ee8d421-490444ac9bfc2da3.","errors":{"$":["'I' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."]}}

Here is the JSON that I send:

```
{
    BndPublicado: false
    ChrCodAcceso: "C3C-007-000"
    ChrCookie: "sysses=fmHUrLdB3PLw1kpM5nW1c7AxI/yFUIkbM6Y4p8tN2ftUsWLiPfSBImg6AGnxnuiJYU/BOiToidI/gC5Lh+XzCvtOlGP6jwOPcdfM6tn5nAEQriqQR5Xqpa17/sFweUuOe1JckjC1JevQ9kBhlBICKA=="
    IntCGE: 1
    IntEmpresa: 1
    IntUsuario: 1
}
```

Here is the call from AJAX

```
function fn_ValidateAccess (p_Access){

    var v_PathExternal = 'http://localhost:40452/EXAMPLE..';

    var v_PostJSON = fn_CreateSessionData(p_Access);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: v_PathExternal,
        dataType: "json",
        data: v_PostJSON,
        success: function (data){ 
          return data;
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
            return null;
        },
        error: function (data){ 
            alert("No se ha podido completar la validación de acceso." + data.responseText); 
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the Startup of my service:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Policy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<GetValuesDropDownList>());

        services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetValuesDropDownList.Handler).Assembly);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

And here is my controller

```
        [ResponseType(typeof(Task<ActionResult<ResultsValidateAccess>>))]
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ResultsValidateAccess>> postValidarSession([FromBody] ValidateAccess.Execute request)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(request);
        }
```

Comment: When debugging,can your web api get the data from ajax?If not can you share the model in your web api,the error seems like your json is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that this was happened when ModelBinder tried to deserialize DATA that posted from Ajax. The posted data was encoded to not Json format then System.Text.Json.Serialization generated error.

To investigate, please look at the format of data that Ajax post to the controller. Or, try using JSON.stringify() to serialize v_PostJson before sending the request